# Running commands over multiple files and naming of new files

Tags: bash

Here is a bash script I have 5 PCAP files I want to run these commands against them and then name the new files flow1 flow2 flow3 flow4 flow5 after each PCAP file it goes through I cannot get it to name the files right

the new file comes up as 1 long string flow1 flow2 flow3 flow4 flow5 for just 1 of the files

```
flow=(flow1 flow2 flow3 flow4 flow5)
dns=(dns1 dns2 dns3 dns4 dns5 dns6)
ntp=(ntp1 ntp2 ntp3 ntp4 ntp5 ntp6)

#creates a new directory based on the PCAP folder name 
for file in *.pcap
do
argus -r *.pcap -w packet.argus &&
#Run argus to get the flow volumn (totalbytes) and the flow duration (seconds)
#ra -r packet.argus -s bytes dur > flow_vol_dur.csv
ra -r packet.argus -s bytes dur -u > "${flow[*]}.csv"

ra -r packet.argus -n -s bytes dur rate runtime pkts load loss > features.csv &&                                                                       
#Run argus to get the source and destination ports, merge both columns together and count how many occurrences
#racluster -r packet.argus -n -s sport dport > ports.csv &&
ra -r packet.argus -n -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 53 > "${dns[*]}.csv" 
ra -r packet.argus -n -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 123 > "${ntp[*]}.csv" &&

rm packet.argus 

done
```

Comment: There are some clear problems: 1) Your `for` loop is iterating over all of the `*.pcap` files in the current directory and placing each on in the `${file}` variable, but you are not using that variable in any of the commands in your loop. 2) the STDOUT redirect operator (`>`) takes a single filename. You are passing `"${flow[*]}.csv"`, which is a single string containing all of the elements of the `flow` array. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what the `argus` and `ra` commands do, I suspect this is closer to what you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
for file in *.pcap; do
  ((count++))
  argus -r ${file} -w packet.argus
  ra -r packet.argus -s bytes dur -u > flow${count}.csv
  ra -r packet.argus -n -s bytes dur rate runtime pkts load loss > features.csv
  ra -r packet.argus -n -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 53 > dns${count}.csv 
  ra -r packet.argus -n -s stime ltime sport dport - dst port 123 > ntp${count}.csv
  rm packet.argus 
done
```

Comment: thank you do you know i can delete the packet.argus file everytime there is a new loop?

Comment: I believe that the `packet.argus` file is created by the `argus` command at the start of each look and can safely be deleted at the end of each loop, as it is in line 11 of my script. If this is a problem, simply move line 11 outside the loop.